# SQL Error converting data type nvarchar to float

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am getting an error

> Error converting data type nvarchar to float

in this part of my stored procedure:

```
 SELECT 
     CAST(RTRIM(Value) AS FLOAT)     
 FROM 
     table_1
 WHERE 
     ISNUMERIC(RTRIM(Value)) = 1 
     AND RTRIM(Value) NOT LIKE '%[^0-9.]%'
```

I tried to track down the value that would have caused this but was unable to do so and now the procedure runs successfully so I don't have the ability to track down the problematic value format.

If someone can suggest a way I would like to know what value could have pass through the 2 checks we have.

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you working with?

Comment: Instead of float cast decimal(18,4) it supports better  numbers like "18.4".

Comment: Your logic looks airtight to me.  Are you sure that it wasn't working completely perhaps after you had removed all problematic data?

Comment: `SELECT 
     case when Value <> '' 
            then cast(cast(value as nvarchar(50)) as float) 
          ELSE 0.0` to find problem value

Comment: For starters, `ISNUMERIC('-') = 1`, but `CAST('-' AS FLOAT)` is an error. Then there's the fact that [`WHERE` doesn't always protect you](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/32912431-sql-server-should-not-raise-illogical-errors), although that should not be in effect for a trivial `SELECT` like this. `TRY_CAST` and `TRY_CONVERT` are your friends, if you have them; `CASE` often bails you out as well (but is unfortunately still not foolproof in the face of some aggressive optimizations).

Comment: I am using SQL server 2008

Answer (score 1):

Use `TRY_CONVERT()` instead

```
SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(10, 0), RTRIM(Value)) as Col
FROM table_1
WHERE TRY_CONVERT((DECIMAL(10, 0), Value) IS NOT NULL;
--WHERE ISNUMERIC(RTRIM(Value)) = 1 AND RTRIM(Value) NOT LIKE '%[^0-9.]%'
```

Comment: `TRY_CONVERT` is a **new feature** in SQL Server **2012** which is therefore not available to the OP of this question

Answer (score 0):

If you had SQL Server 2012 or newer you could use `TRY_CONVERT` instead of `ISNUMERIC`

```
SELECT TRY_CONVERT(FLOAT, RTRIM(Value))
FROM table_1
WHERE RTRIM(Value) NOT LIKE '%[^0-9.]%'
```

In your case you should add additional conditions to the `WHERE` clause (I was able to come up with two):

```
SELECT 
     CAST(RTRIM(Value) AS FLOAT)     
 FROM 
     table_1
 WHERE 
     ISNUMERIC(RTRIM(Value)) = 1 
     AND RTRIM(Value) NOT LIKE '%[^0-9.]%'
     AND RTRIM(Value) != '.'
     AND RTRIM(Value) NOT LIKE '%.%.%'
```

Comment: I am using CAST and not ISNUMERIC to convert

Comment: I suggest you read the topic "Functional misuse" from this article to understand the difference https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/basics-good-t-sql-coding-style/

Comment: Thanks, @marc_s, I had answered before the version was specified